# Number of ways n unknots can be configured into an n-bridge link?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I have n-unknots (trivial knots) embedded in $S^3$ with the condition that they form an n-bridge link. I'm trying to find the different ways they can be put together.

So far I only have the trivial solution of an n-component unlink. In trying to find the bridge number of different link configurations, I'm somewhat at a loss, as all of the papers I've come across only apply to knots and not links. I haven't been able to find info on the bridge number for something even as simple as the Hopf link.

Please help! I suspect there aren't that many configurations, at least not compared to the n-bridge knot. Thank you!

Comment: The bridge number of the Hopf link is 2. (I was going to point you toward LinkInfo, but it looks like they don't have this data.)  Also, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  Is it "how many n-bridge n-component Brunnian links are there?"

Comment: @KyleMiller thank you, yes that is the question, though they don't have to be brunnian.

Comment: The Whitehead link is another 2-component bridge-number-2 link of unknots.  You can add arbitrarily many twists to one of the components preserving this property, so the answer is "infinitely many."

Comment: Another example infinite family of 2-component bridge-number-2 links of unknots is from adding arbitrarily many twists between the two components of a Hopf link.  I believe this family has no links in common with the previous family.

Comment: @KyleMiller.   Thank you! I didn't realize twists preserve bridge number.

Comment: I'm just thinking about the diagram that presents the bridge number -- I wouldn't say this is a general principle.  Something I also remembered in the interim is that every 2-bridge 2-component link has unknotted components.  It turns out the have all been classified (see the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-bridge_knot)).

Comment: @KyleMiller without getting too deep into it, I've just realized that in my application all odd number twists are equivalent and all even twists are equivalent to an unlink. This should simplify the problem dramatically!? I'm getting $2^n$ configurations then, maybe you could confirm that?